# I am searching for Regex for employeeId for Jsf

Tags: java, regex

I have one Regex that contains this expression

```
String EmployeeIdPattern = "^[^\\d-\\s][A-Z0-9].*(?<!0)";
```

I am looking for which can take minimum 3 character like A001 but last character should not matched like A0000 so how I block ending zero and It should not take any special character. like@#$%%*()_+,It should block whitespaces at the start and end
I want to pass,S023,S001... like that..

Answer (score 0):

Check it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line="A0000";
        String EmployeeIdPattern = "[A-Z][0-9]*[1-9]";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(EmployeeIdPattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println("Matched");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Notmated");
        }
    }
```